# Storing Values IN Database, working on Emulator But Stop working on Phone

Tags: android, database, android-emulator, localhost

`android:installLocation="auto"`This statement causing problem.... 
i am working on a project where i am taking name from user then saving it in SQL DB.My DB is on localhost. When i run my app in Emulator it work fine, values store in DB perfectly. But when i try to run it on my phone.... i need to add this statement in Manifest file (don't need to write this statement when running on Emulator) (android:installLocation="auto"). App does Not work on Phone without writing this statement and gives installation error so adding this statement is mandatory. But app "Unfortunately Stop" when i enter the value n press enter button.

Comment: what do u mean by sql db in localhost?? Not an sqlite db in the android application??

Comment: No not sqlite. Storing values in external DB. DB is on wamp PHPMyAdmin. As according to idea of my app i will store location of every user and later give access to different user to use this DB its kind of social media.

Answer (score 0):

android:installLocation="auto" means [android will determine where your app will be installed (internal or external)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) depending on space availability. If your DB is not on Android, your android app should be pointed at the IP address of the system where your DB server is located.

Emulator can access your development system [through local network](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking). I assume by "localhost" you mean local development system. If you used "localhost" for IP address it will simply point to local IP (emulator or phone), not DB server. I would change it to the IP address of DB server.